# How can a->b depend on selected stack frame if a has the same value?

Tags: c++, gdb

While debugging a segmentation fault using `gdb`, I got this very weird behaviour:

```
(gdb) select 4
(gdb) p mrb
$3 = (mrb_state *) 0x555555dcc000
(gdb) p mrb->eStandardError_class
$4 = (RClass *) 0x0
(gdb) select 3
(gdb) p mrb
$6 = (mrb_state *) 0x555555dcc000
(gdb) p mrb->eStandardError_class
$7 = (struct RClass *) 0x555556015190
```

I don't understand, because in both cases the `mrb` variable points towards the same place in memory, `0x555555dcc000`, but in one case `mrb->eStandardError_class` is null, while in the other, it has a meaningful value.

How is this possible ? Is this a `gdb` bug ? A compiler bug ? Or is this somehow normal ? Could `mrb->eStandardError_class` be a register in one stack frame and a memory value in another ?

**To make it more clear:** I am not running any code between the two calls to `p mrb->eStandardError_class`. So I am not expecting that value to change. How can it be frame-dependent ?

**Edit** following Matteo Italia's suggestion, I have:

```
(gdb) p &(((mrb_state *)0)->eStandardError_class)
$8 = (struct RClass **) 0x170
(gdb) select 4
(gdb) p &(((mrb_state *)0)->eStandardError_class)
$9 = (RClass **) 0x160
```

So it looks like the two units have not been compiled with the same options.

Comment: Something is corrupting the data in that address after you enter the new frame. Use a data breakpoint to discover what.

Comment: @StoryTeller The problem is not that the value has changed, the problem is that gdb gives me a stack-dependent value for dereferencing the same pointer.

Comment: By select I think you actually mean `select-frame` which implies that the variable was assigned in frame 3 and is not anymore in frame 4.

Comment: @2A-66-42 No, because the value of `mrb` is the same in both frames.

Comment: What's even weirder to me is `(RClass *)` vs. `(struct RClass *)`.

Comment: Are the two stack frames in different translation units? Maybe this executable comes from a botched compilation, where the two TUs see a different definition of `mrb_state`/`RClass`?

Comment: Go into the first stack frame and do `p &(((mrb_state *)0)->eStandardError_class)`; do the same in the other one. Does it output different values?

Comment: @MatteoItalia You have caught the problem. Could you develop that into an answer I could accept ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond: great! It's done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(moving from the comments)

If the two stack frames in different translation units, is is possible that the executable comes from a botched compilation, where the two TUs see a different definition of `mrb_state`/`RClass`. This generally happens when the definition of a `struct`/`class` is changed, but not all modules that use it get recompiled. In this case, this is particularly likely given that gdb talks about `RClass *` in one stack frame and `struct RClass *` in the other - it may be a hint that it is talking about different types.

You can quickly check if this is the case by executing

```
p &(((mrb_state *)0)->eStandardError_class)
```

in the two stack frames - if the offset of that member is different, it's confirmed that the two TUs have a different idea about what `mrb_state` is.